# Let $p_1$, $p_2$, ... $p_k$ be prime integers. If $n = p_1p_2...p_k + 1$, then for every $i =1, 2...,p$ does not divide n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I'm told to this by contradiction which seems quite simple at first, but I think I might be neglecting something.

I would simply let $n$ be $p_1p_2...p_k + 1$. And let $m$ equal $p_1p_2..p_k$. I then say $m$ divides $n$. However, it is clear that $m$ is not a divisor: $\frac{n}{m}$ would result in 1 + plus a rational number, hence I've arrived at my contradiction.

Is this correct, something tells me the correct formal way (even though it wouldn't make a difference) of the proof would begin by stating "Let $p_1$, $p_2$,..$p_k$ be composite integers."

Comment: Think about the remainder of the division, it is 1, so...

Comment: **Hint** $\,\ p\mid pn\!+\!1\,\Rightarrow\, pm = pn\!+\!1 \,\Rightarrow\, p(m\!-\!n) = 1\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid 1\ \ $